# Smart mechanism to determine versions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I read a version range and need to return all the serials for the suitable labs (if more than one lab returns it should be an array with a comma between the serials).

I have 4 labs (for now, there will be more:
Lab1 has version 8.6.22
Lab1 has version 8.6.32
Lab1 has version 8.6.41
Lab1 has version 8.6.51

Let's take a simple example while the range is: 8.6.22-8.6.22
In this case, the function should return the serial of lab1

Example 2:
The range is 8.6.32-8.6.32
The function returns the serial of lab2

Example 3:
The range is 8.6.22-8.6.32
The function return the serials of lab1 and lab2 with a comma between

Example 4:
The range is 8.6.20-10.0
The function returns all the serials as an array with a comma

I hope it's clear
The returned serials should be according to the range

I started to create something and need your help.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum lab
   {
      lab1,
      lab2,
      lab3,
      lab4
   }
"@
```

This is the order of the labs:

```
"Lab1 = 8.6.22"
"Lab2 = 8.6.32"
"Lab3 = 8.6.41"
"Lab4 = 8.6.51"
```

I tried to replace lab1,lab2,lab3,lab4 with serials but got an exception

See below the function that returns the right lab only for a dedicated version, I need to return serials and cover more cases as mentioned above

```
function ParseLab ($range) {
    $start, $end = [version[]] ($range.Split('-'))
    if ($start -ge '8.6.22' -and $end -le '8.6.23.0') {
        return [lab]::lab1   
    }
    elseif ($start -ge '8.6.32' -and $end -le '8.6.33.0') {
        return [lab]::lab2    
    }
    elseif ($start -ge '8.6.41' -and $end -le '8.6.42.0') {
        return [lab]::lab3    
    }   
    elseif ($start -ge '8.6.51' -and $end -le '8.6.52.0') {
        return [lab]::lab4    
    }
}
```

For a range of 7.4-8.6.50, I am supposed to get a list of 3 serials:

```
$serials = (serial1,serial2,serial3)
```

I can add a function that returns the serial but still only for 1 lab

```
function GetSerial ($lab) {
    switch ($lab) {
    Lab1 {
        return "ba41-aa9b-c860-413c"
    }
    Lab2 {
         return "ba41-aa9b-c860-4545"    
    }
    Lab3 {
        return "ba41-er9b-c860-4545"     
    }
    Lab4 {
        return "ba23-er9b-c860-4545"
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: When you say "returned machines should be according to the largest range", can you clarify what you mean by "largest range", and maybe show a couple of examples of how you determine the "largest range"? For example, do you mean the range with the highest *start* version? Highest *end* version? Or the range with the widest difference between start and end regardless of the actual version values? And what happens if, for example, ranges overlap? There seem to be two parts to this problem (i) selecting the right range to search (ii) determining the machine matches for that range.

Comment: Are those the only 2 options (a range of versions or a wildcard version) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PowerShell v5+ solution that relies on custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es (see the source-code comments as well as the high-level description further below):

```bash
# -- Sample code that demonstrates the use of the classes defined later.

# Initialize the array of [Lab] objects.
[Lab[]] $labs = 
  [Lab]::new('lab1', '8.6.22', 'ba41-aa9b-c860-413c'),
  [Lab]::new('lab2', '8.6.32', 'ba41-aa9b-c860-4545'),
  [Lab]::new('lab3', '8.6.41', 'ba41-er9b-c860-4545'),
  [Lab]::new('lab4', '8.6.51', 'ba23-er9b-c860-4545')

# Initialize a version-range evaluator, here with a single range.
$rangeEvaluator = [LabVersionRangeEvaluator]::new(@('7.4-8.6.50'))

# Pass the labs to the range evaluator and ask it to return
# the list of labs that fall into the stored range(s), then
# join their .Serial property values with ','
$listOfSerials =
  $rangeEvaluator.GetMatchingLabs($labs).Serial -join ','

# Output the result, i.e. a string containing the ","-separated
# list of serials of those labs that fall into the specified range.
# -> 'ba41-aa9b-c860-413c,ba41-aa9b-c860-4545,ba41-er9b-c860-4545'
$listOfSerials

# --- Class definitions

# A single lab.
class Lab {
  # Properties
  [string] $Name
  [version] $Version
  [string] $Serial
  # Constructor
  Lab([string] $name, [version] $version, [string] $serial) {
    $this.Name = $name
    $this.Version = $version
    $this.Serial = $serial
  }
}

# An evaluator for whether a given list of labs falls into any one of
# a list of version-number ranges specified on construction.
# Version-number ranges can be:
#  * either: '<from>-<to>'
#    * e.g., '7.4-8.6.50' matches all versions between 7.4 and 8.6.50, inclusively.
#  * or: '<from>'
#    * e.g., '8.6' matches all 8.6.x.x versions
class LabVersionRangeEvaluator {

  # Properties: The endpoints for the stored version ranges.
  [version[]] $start
  [version[]] $end

  # Constructor
  LabVersionRangeEvaluator([string[]] $ranges) {
    $this.start = [version[]]::new($ranges.Count)
    $this.end = [version[]]::new($ranges.Count)
    [int[]] $components = $null
    $i = 0
    foreach ($range in $ranges) {
      $pass = 0
      $vers = $range -split '-', 2
      if ($vers.Count -eq 1) { $vers += $vers[0] }
      foreach ($pass in 0..1) {
        $components = $vers[$pass] -split '\.'
        if ($pass -eq 0) {
          # Trim trailing .0 components so as to make them -1 in the resulting
          # [version] instance, so that something like 8.6 >= 8.6.0 works.
          # (Note that [version] '8.6' -ge [version] '8.6.0' returns $false,
          #  due to the internal -1 components for .Build and .Revision in 
          #  [version] '8.6')
          $j = $components.Count
          while ($components[--$j] -eq 0) {  }
          $this.start[$i] = [version]::new.Invoke([object[]] $components[0..$j])
        }
        else {
          # Fill in the unspecified components with [int]::MaxValue
          $components += (, [int]::MaxValue) * (4 - $components.Count)
          $this.end[$i] = [version]::new.Invoke([object[]] $components)
        }
      }
      ++$i
    }
  }
  
  # Given a list of labs, return the sublist that falls into the stored range(s).
  [Lab[]] GetMatchingLabs([Lab[]] $labs) {
    $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Lab]]::new()
    :next_lab foreach ($lab in $labs) {
      foreach ($i in 0..($this.start.Count - 1)) {
        if ($lab.Version -ge $this.start[$i] -and $lab.Version -le $this.end[$i]) {
          $results.Add($lab)
          continue next_lab
        }
      }
    }
    return $results.ToArray()
  }
}
```

The following high-level explanation was contributed by [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190564/darin) (reformatted and lightly edited by me):

- The code introduces two custom classes: `Lab` and `LabVersionRangeEvaluator`, defined towards the end of the provided script. Initially, the script creates individual Lab instances, each representing a lab with specific attributes like name, version, and serial number. These Lab instances are collectively stored in an array named `$labs`. Subsequently, an instance of `LabVersionRangeEvaluator` is created, assigned to the variable `$rangeEvaluator`. This instance is crucial for defining the version range you wish to evaluate against the labs.
- The core functionality unfolds when the `.GetMatchingLabs()` method of the `$rangeEvaluator` instance is invoked. This method, integral to the `LabVersionRangeEvaluator` class, takes the `$labs` array as input. It processes this input to identify and return labs matching the predefined version range. By appending `.Serial` to the method call (`.GetMatchingLabs()`), the script specifically extracts the serial numbers of the matching labs, rather than returning complete lab objects. These serial numbers are then [joined with `,` to form a single string and] stored in the `$listOfSerials` variable, ready for further use or display.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand the logic and how to use it
Maybe you can write some instructions please

Comment: I don't see the function and how to set an input (the input is the range )
The range is changing, did you implement it also?

Comment: @Bandit: As for how to use it: I was hoping that the first section of the code, before the first `class` declaration, would suffice as an explanation. There is no `function`, only instances of classes and method calls: one class represent labs, and the other implements a version-range evaluator. There are comments in the code; explaining what it does in detail would amount to a lot of prose. Do you have specific questions beyond the one I just answered?

Comment: Thank you again, I don't know how to use your code
I need a function that gets a range and returns the right serials as I wrote in my question

Comment: @Bandit: the code is fully self-contained, using sample lab definitions and a sample version range, `'7.4-8.6.50'`. If you run it, it should behave as described in your question. Is that not the case for  you? If not, what happens instead?

Comment: When I run it, where can I see the results? I mean the output serials

Comment: @Bandit: They print to the display; when I run it, I see `ba41-aa9b-c860-413c,ba41-aa9b-c860-4545,ba41-er9b-c860-4545` Don't you? I've updated the answer to show how to (also) capture the results in a variable, but it's as simple as prepending `$results = ...` to a command.

Comment: @Bandit, mklement0's code introduces two custom classes: Lab and LabVersionRangeEvaluator, defined towards the end of the provided script. Initially, the script creates individual Lab instances, each representing a lab with specific attributes like name, version, and serial number. These Lab instances are collectively stored in an array named $labs.

Subsequently, an instance of LabVersionRangeEvaluator is created, assigned to the variable $rangeEvaluator. This instance is crucial for defining the version range you wish to evaluate against the labs.

Comment: The core functionality unfolds when the GetMatchingLabs method of the $rangeEvaluator instance is invoked. This method, integral to the LabVersionRangeEvaluator class, takes the $labs array as input. It processes this input to identify and return labs matching the predefined version range. By appending .Serial to the method call (GetMatchingLabs), the script specifically extracts the serial numbers of the matching labs, rather than returning complete lab objects. These serial numbers are then stored in the $ListOfSerials variable, ready for further use or display.

Comment: Ok, now I see the output ... but the $results is empty. what should I need to do to capture the serial into $results? 
Regarding the input range, should I need to insert a variable into this line?
$rangeEvaluator = [LabVersionRangeEvaluator]::new(@('8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999'))
$ver = "8.6.22-8.6.22"
$rangeEvaluator = [LabVersionRangeEvaluator]::new(@($ver)) ??

Comment: @Bandit, the last sentence in my last comment explains where the results are.

Comment: There is no $ListOfSerials as you wrote...
Can you help to figure how to capture the output?

Comment: I see the $ListOfSerials=
I got an error 

Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
At line:90 char:11
+           $results.Add($lab)
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Bandit; note that `$listOfSerials` contains a _string_ containing the serials separated with `,`, as requested - if you want to capture the serials _as an array_, simply omit the `-join ','` operation.

Comment: @Bandit: Re `[LabVersionRangeEvaluator]` construction: yes, that's how you'd pass a variable. Note that you can pass _multiple_ ranges, if needed.

Comment: Great, do you know why I got the error?

Comment: @Bandit: The error is very strange - does it really occur with the code in the question? Try restarting the session to see if it persists.

Comment: Thank you. not I don't have this error, I am very curious about  your answer: the Note that you can pass multiple ranges 
What will be the output in this case of multiple ranges?

Comment: @Bandit: The output logic is the same, it's just that _all_ ranges are compared against (each lab's version is checked to see if it falls into _any_ of the stored ranges), so that potentially more of the input labs match.

Comment: What about overlap? will work? just curious, this was not part of the original question :)

Comment: @Bandit: It doesn't check for overlap. The stored ranges are processed in sequence, and as soon as a given lab object's version number falls into a range, it is added to the array of output labs.

Comment: Currently, I do not need the overlap, do you think it will be possible? should be easy? 
I want to know, maybe I will need it and will open a new question :)

Comment: @Bandit: I think that would require clarifying the exact logic and will likely make the implementation quite a bit more complex, so you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: @mklement0 how can it be that for range 7.5-8.6 retrievers all the labs? for 7.5-8.6.51 is clear

Comment: @bandit, as explained in the source-code comments, `8.6` matches `8.6.x.x`, i.e _any_ build and revision components, and therefore matches all sample labs.

Comment: Hi @mklement0, I have a strange behavior and maybe you can help :)
I added to $labs an additional variable (branch) after the version for every column.
[Lab]::new('lab1', '8.6.22', 'v8.6.22' 'ba41-aa9b-c860-413c').
I added a counter:
$count = $rangeEvaluator.GetMatchingLabs($labs).Name
Creating a long string with ';' between the values.
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $count ; $i++) {
    $ListOfLabs += $listOfversions[$i] + ";" + $listOfbranches[$i] + ";" + $listOfserials[$i]
}
It's working great for more than 1 lab. when there is only 1 lab I got only the first letter of each variable

Comment: Forgot this at the end 
$ListOfLabs = $ListOfLabs -join ','

Comment: @Bandit, wrap the variables in `@(...)` to ensure that they're treated as an array so as to make the indexing work as intended, e.g. `@($listOfversions)[$i]`