# Determine overlap versions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I asked a similar question and got an answer.
This is the question link
[Smart mechanism to determine versions in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77811253/smart-mechanism-to-determine-versions-in-powershell/77812640?noredirect=1#comment137194362_77812640)
I need to make some changes in the code to resolve my new scenario.
I made some changes and the logic seems ok but not sure. therefore need your professionalism.
Even if it's working it's not good enough and I will explain

The new goal is to get a list of versions dynamically (I have an object that holds the possible versions). according to the range I supply the script should return all the versions within the range (including the edges, for example, if the range is 8.6.22-8.6.32, the result should be 8.6.22,8.6.32). I added manually the [List[]] $versions rows but it should be dynamic because I have an object with all the possible versions. it means [List[]] $versions should built automatically!!
This should be ok? in case $results is the list of possible versions?

```
[List[]] $versions = $results

# Initialize the array of [Lab] objects.
[List[]] $versions = 
  [List]::new('8.6.22'),
  [List]::new('8.6.32'),
  [List]::new('8.6.13'),
  [List]::new('8.6.40'),
  [List]::new('8.6.41'),
  [List]::new('8.6.51')
  

# Initialize a version-range evaluator, here with a single range.
$rangeEvaluator = [LabVersionRangeEvaluator]::new(@('8.6.22-8.6.60'))

$list = $rangeEvaluator.GetMatchingLabs($versions).version -join ','

$list

# --- Class definitions

# A single lab.
class List {
  # Properties
  [version] $Version
  # Constructor
 List([string] $version) {

    $this.Version = $version

  }
}


class LabVersionRangeEvaluator {

  # Properties: The endpoints for the stored version ranges.
  [version[]] $start
  [version[]] $end

  # Constructor
  LabVersionRangeEvaluator([string[]] $ranges) {
    $this.start = [version[]]::new($ranges.Count)
    $this.end = [version[]]::new($ranges.Count)
    [int[]] $components = $null
    $i = 0
    foreach ($range in $ranges) {
      $pass = 0
      $vers = $range -split '-', 2
      if ($vers.Count -eq 1) { $vers += $vers[0] }
      foreach ($pass in 0..1) {
        $components = $vers[$pass] -split '\.'
        if ($pass -eq 0) {
          # Trim trailing .0 components so as to make them -1 in the resulting
          # [version] instance, so that something like 8.6 >= 8.6.0 works.
          # (Note that [version] '8.6' -ge [version] '8.6.0' returns $false,
          #  due to the internal -1 components for .Build and .Revision in 
          #  [version] '8.6')
          $j = $components.Count
          while ($components[--$j] -eq 0) {  }
          $this.start[$i] = [version]::new.Invoke([object[]] $components[0..$j])
        }
        else {
          # Fill in the unspecified components with [int]::MaxValue
          $components += (, [int]::MaxValue) * (4 - $components.Count)
          $this.end[$i] = [version]::new.Invoke([object[]] $components)
        }
      }
      ++$i
    }
  }
  
  # Given a list of labs, return the sublist that falls into the stored range(s).
  [List[]] GetMatchingLabs([List[]] $versions) {
    $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[List]]::new()
    :next_lab foreach ($ver in $versions) {
      foreach ($i in 0..($this.start.Count - 1)) {
        if ($ver.Version -ge $this.start[$i] -and $ver.Version -le $this.end[$i]) {
          $results.Add($ver)
          continue next_lab
        }
      }
    }
    return $results.ToArray()
  }
}
```

Comment: As an aside: `List` is a supremely confusing name for a class that wraps a single object and has no list-like functionality :)

Comment: understood, except for the name, the code is right? should I need to change something?

Comment: I mean, it's unnecessarily complicated - `[version]`'s are comparable so this problem can be solved using `Where-Object` and `Sort-Object` alone.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. maybe you can write the answer. where should I need to use Where-Object and Sort-Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[version]` type implements the [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) interface, meaning you can use comparison operators like `-ge` and `-le` directly on them:

```
function Get-VersionInRange {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [version[]]$Version,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [version]$Start,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [version]$End
  )

  begin {
    $versionsInRange = [System.Collections.Generic.List[version]]::new()
  }

  process {
    $Version |Where-Object { $Start -le $_ -and $_ -le $End } |ForEach-Object {
      $versionsInRange.Add($_)
    }
  }

  end {
    # sort list of matching versions
    $versionsInRange.Sort()

    # return sorted list of versions in range
    return $versionsInRange

   ##  the following would've worked too
   # 
   # return $versionsInRange |Sort-Object

  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
[version[]]$versions = @(
    '8.6.22'
    '8.6.32'
    '8.6.13'
    '8.6.40'
    '8.6.41'
    '8.6.51'
)

$versionsInRange = $versions |Get-VersionInRange -Start 8.6.22 -End 8.6.32
# if you're afraid of piping input you can also do:
# $versionsInRange = Get-VersionInRange -Version $versions -Start 8.6.22 -End 8.6.32

$versionsInRange -join ', '
```

Comment: Thank you but the result is not a list of versions. I get 
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
8      6      22     -1      
8      6      32     -1

The original script is not good?

Comment: @Bandit you're seeing the default formatting of a naked `[version]` object. If you want to wrap it in custom object, just tack `|Select-Object @{Name='Version';Expression={$_}}` onto the last pipeline and you'll get the same output formatting as before

Comment: Thank you @Mathias.
Now the output is 

Version
-------
8.6.22 
8.6.31 
8.6.32 

First I don't want to see the version title and second I need this object with a comma between the versions -join ','

Comment: Then use `-join`

Comment: Its not working and I do not  need the 'Version caption'

Comment: @Bandit Did you see the update to my answer? You shouldn't do the `Select-Object` step if you don't want to wrap it the same way your `[List]` class does

Comment: What does this input [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [version[]]$Version,
?
When you call the function you don't supply this variable

Comment: @Bandit I do - I'm supplying values via the pipeline :)

Comment: I tried to delete this raw but the script failed

Comment: @Bandit I don't know what "delete this raw" means - if you script fails, please include the error message

Comment: After deletion 

Get-VersionInRange : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters 
that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\ncarmona\OneDrive - Varonis\Scripts\versions_Range2.ps1:46 char:31
+ ... onsInRange = $versions |Get-VersionInRange -Start '8.5' -End '8.6.50'
+

Comment: @Bandit Wait, you removed the parameter definition (even though I told you it's what the input objects were being bound to), and now you can no longer bind pipeline input to any parameters? I'm gonna let you figure that out on your own :)

Comment: Why would you remove it? You can use the pipeline, or you can pass an array of versions as a named parameter just fine with the function presented in my answer